# laravel Error: PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying save a register in my MySQL database using Eloquent of Laravel 5.

PHP version 5.6 I installed via .htaccess

> Use PHP5.6 as default
>   ?AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

It will occur the following error on server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to install php5-mysql extension on your system.

Comment: but i install php5 via  .htaccess ,  .htaccess code is  
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php . you can see this link => http://nawabpur.com/info.php , php version show 5.6

Comment: you cannot "install" anything via .htaccess??